# MySQL exceptions not caught (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

My C# program works with a MySQL database.

For some reason the program cannot catch exceptions caused my the MySQL connection.

Example:

If I make the credentials in the connection string invalid, the program crashes like this (even when running in the debugger): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7KVe.jpg

The connection code is like this:

```
using MySQLDriverCS;

namespace XXX
{
    public class Data
    {
        private static MySQLConnection con;

        static Data()
        {
            string connectionString = new MySQLConnectionString("XXX",
                "XXX",
                "XXX",
                "XXX").AsString;

            con = new MySQLConnection(connectionString + ";CharSet=utf8");
            con.Open(); // For testing the connection
            con.Close();
        }
...
```

Any ideas for how I can improve things and start catching MySQL exceptions?

I have tried wrapping the code in the static constructor in a try-catch. That didn't help. The program still crashed in the same way.

Thanks.

---

Same code with the try-catch wrapper. It still fails with the same error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7KVe.jpg

```
    static Data()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = new MySQLConnectionString("XXX",
                "XXX",
                "XXX",
                "XXX").AsString;

            con = new MySQLConnection(connectionString + ";CharSet=utf8");
            con.Open(); // For testing the connection
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try just passing the connection string into the mysqlconnection object instead of using the mysqlconnectionstring object

Comment: "exception not caught" because there is no try-catch block. Try to add try-catch block and you can see the error.

Comment: I have tried wrapping the code in the static constructor in a try-catch. That didn't help. The program still crashed in the same way.

Comment: You get this error because it's running hosted and debugger is not configured for unmanaged code. Go to the properties of your project and check Debug and Build tabs. You should be able to enable unmanaged code debugging there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the appropriate exception type in the catch block.

Use the appropriate **MySQL classes**.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

// class level var or whatnot:
string connString = @"server=theHostName;userid=dbuser123;password=OpenSesame7;database=my_db_name";


public void connect()
{
    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connString); // read above comments for (conn)
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
        string s="MySqlException: "+ex.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(s,"Error",buttons);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            //conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Caught No Problem:**

[image]

Add References screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have tried wrapping the code in the static constructor in a try-catch. That didn't help. The program still crashed in the same way.

Comment: I will try to screw up my connection string

Comment: No problem catching my error. Error trap screen shown above in White

Comment: Sometimes people  forget they are compiling to debug, but running the old release code. idk what you are doing or your references or classes. Good luck :p

Comment: Using MySql.Data.MySqlClient instead of MySQLDriverCS helped a lot. Now I get an exception. Thanks a lot! - guess it's now time to do some code refactoring.

Comment: yea. all's well that ends well.

Answer (score -1):

Catching or handling exceptions in C# generally requires a `try-catch` statement.

The syntax is essentially as follows:

```
try
{
    // operation likely to cause error
} 
catch (Exception e){
    // handle error
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);
}

Console.Read();
```

So wrap your `con.Open()` logic in a `try-catch` statement like so:

```
try
{
    Con.Open();
} 
catch (Exception e){
    // handle error
    Console.WriteLine("Possible MySQL Exception: " + e);
}
```

Additionally, you can add a `finally` block to the end of a `try-catch` statement, which executes its code regardless of whether an exception was handled or not:

```
    try
{
    // attempt to do something here
    con.Open();
} 
catch (Exception e){
    // handle error
    Console.Writeline("Exception: " + e);
}
finally 
{
    Console.Writeline("This runs no matter if an exception is thrown or not!");
}

Console.Read();
```

Comment: I have tried wrapping the code in the static constructor in a try-catch. That didn't help. The program still crashed in the same way.