# c# Mysql connection error

Tags: c#, php, mysql

Basically I am trying to connect to my MYSQL Server which is running on my raspberry pi, i can ping the pi and such but when i try to connect to the database through c# i get an error, ive tried many things but nothing seems to be working, im down to just the server IP but yet that issent working.

The error i get : An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

My MYSQL server up and running: http://prntscr.com/btqv6l ( screenshot )

My C# code where i get the error:

```
private void sqlreader()
{

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string connString = @"server=192.168.1.140;userid=JohnSmith;password=blahblah;database=someDB";
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `temp`", con);
        List<decimal> data = new List<decimal>();
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            decimal TotalValue = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string Read = reader.GetString("temp");
                Read = Read.Replace('.', ',');
                data.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(Read));
                TotalValue += Convert.ToDecimal(Read);
            }
            decimal total = TotalValue / data.Count();
            lbAveragetemp.Content = decimal.Round(total, 2);
            lbLowtemp.Content = data.Min();
            lbMaxtemp.Content = data.Max();

        }
    }

         catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

    }
```

[The exception it throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo6V2.png)

Sorry for bad explanation hopefully you guys understand.

Comment: Here is a real basic one I wrote [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38277659/1816093). If it survives the try/catch, sweet times.

Comment: The program opens but nothing happens since the connection to the database failed, i have no problem no problem getting data into the database on the PI through Localhost. I have tried with specifying the port also but that diddnt seem to work either.

Comment: You aren't showing much, like a real useful connection string. I suggest you improve your question submissions :p

Comment: no database, no username, no password.... like a wrong connection string.

Comment: That is why I showed the link which has, well, using blocks and try/catch

Comment: haha sry about this im new to the whole stackoverflow thing :) here is all the code im trying to execute includeing all the mysql connections: http://pastebin.com/mHnvcdQh i hope its okay with pastebin link ^^

Comment: why not show the `ex` info versus just "error"

Comment: haha my bad man thanks for helping i can't upvote or give reputation yet but kudos to you :)

Comment: trust me I will find you later. j/k

Comment: btw just for further info im useing mysql version 5.0.9.0 ive used it in a few other projects and it have worked like a charm everytime but could it be that my PI is running a newer version and my version is too old for them to work together?

Comment: I don't know anything about R pi. Is it like running on a wrist watch or something

Comment: Well its one of thise https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Raspberry_Pi_B%2B_top.jpg im useing it to get serial information from my arduino and then im hosting a phpmyadmin/mysql server on it and it automaticly uploads the information from my arudino to the database through a simple python script ( Raspberry pi is running on Linux mostly im useing Raspbian which is a smaller version of Debian )